# Why add a trailing slash after an rsync destination?

Tags: rsync

According to [this](http://www.comentum.com/rsync.html) web page, adding '/' to the end of an rsync destination produces a different result from not adding it.

I've tried to test this, but I cannot verify it:

```
$ mkdir dir{1..3}
$ touch dir1/file
$ rsync -r dir1/ dir2
$ rsync -r dir1/ dir3/
$ ls dir*
dir1:
file

dir2:
file

dir3:
file
```

Does appending a '/' to the destination actually have a use sometimes?

Comment: Are you referring to this part of the man page: `A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid  creating  an  additional  directory level at the destination.`?  If so please note how your command is not at all similar to the one in the example given in the man page.

Comment: @Jesse_b Your comment does surprise me... "When using "/" at the end of destination, rsync will paste the data inside the last folder.
When not using "/" at the end of destination, rsync will create a folder with the last destination folder name and paste the data inside that folder."

Comment: @HaukeLaging I'm confused, what is surprising?  This particular section also refers to the trailing slash being on the source.  So if you did `rsync -r dir1/subdir1 dir2/` it will copy the contents of `subdir1` into `dir2` but if you did `rsync -r dir1/subdir1/ dir2/` it will copy the whole directory (including contents) `subdir1` into `dir2` so you would have `./dir2/subdir1/`

Comment: @Jesse_b I did not notice the "man" in your first comment. Quite obviously the OP does not refer to the man page but to the page which he has linked.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Oh duh, didn't even see that.  I think I was skimming too fast and read it as "According to the man page".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It does make a difference when the source is a file and the destination directory does not exist. For instance take a file called `file` as source:

- `$ rsync file dest/` will create a copy of `file` inside a directory `dest`, whereas
- `$ rsync file dest` will make a copy of the file `file` called `dest`

---

To add (from the comments); if a directory `dest` already exists, a copy `file` will be created in `dest` in both cases above.

Basic example:

```
~/test > touch file
~/test > mkdir dest1
mkdir: created directory 'dest1'
~/test > tree
.
├── dest1
└── file

1 directory, 1 file
~/test > rsync file dest1
~/test > rsync file dest2
~/test > rsync file dest3/
~/test > tree
.
├── dest1
│   └── file
├── dest2
├── dest3
│   └── file
└── file

2 directories, 4 files
~/test >
```

Comment: Thank you. So if directory `dest` already exists, there's no need for the trailing slash?

Comment: Exactly. If in the example above a directory `dest` exists, a copy of `file` will be created inside in both cases.